# dphys swapfile error while updating

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, linux, update, rpi-update

So I recently got a new raspberry pi 4 and I went to update it and ran the following commands:
`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. The update command ran perfectly fine but when I ran upgrade I got errors stating this:

```
* dphys-swapfile.service - dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dphys-swapfile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-01-06 10:39:20 GMT; 17ms ago
     Docs: man:dphys-swapfile(8)
  Process: 7793 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7816 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile swapon (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 7816 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
```

```
Jan 06 10:39:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 06 10:39:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
dpkg: error processing package dphys-swapfile (--configure):
 installed dphys-swapfile package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dphys-swapfile
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've done a fair bit of googling and researching but I just can't seem to find anything. I've tried running this command `sudo apt-get reinstall coreutils` to maybe reinstall swapfile but it gave me a similar error. I also tried a fresh flash of Raspbian but the same error came up when I went to update that too. I'm new to linux as this is my first time using it and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Also sorry if I messed up in the format for this post in some way. This is my first post here :)

Comment: run the command ```dpkg-reconfigure dphys-swapfile``` and if it fails, add the errors to your question.   You could probably also try disabling the service with ```systemctl disable dphys-swapfile.service``` but that just covers the problem up.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question lacks detail BUT is tagged rpi-update

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911 Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update)
> documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt update; sudo apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: I couldn't even run that command. I just tried and got the same error that showed:  `Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.`