# Boot from USB 3.0 ports

Tags: usb, boot-issues, bootloader

I want to boot from my USB 3.0 port attached SSD. I have flashed my RPI4 with the Raspberry Pi Imager USB Boot loader.

When I attach my SSD to my USB 2.0 ports it runs flawless. But as soon I connect it to my USB 3.0 port it looks like it doesn't work. The SATA to USB3 cable blue light works in both situations so there seems nothing going wrong.
My ACT (green) LED on the front is flashing very quickly 3 or 4 times and than a second not and then repeats when connected to USB3.0 ports. No difference in wether I use the upper or lower one. The flashing is so quick that I can't see exactly how many flashes it tries to show.

What can be the problem?

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 152d:0578
```

Comment: What USB/Sata controller do you use? JMicron ones can be problematic. Add the output of `lsusb` to your question

Comment: It is an EWENT EW7017 USB3.0 to SATA adapter cable.

Comment: Did you only get numeric output? No additional text apart from the IDs?  Which OS/version do you use?

Comment: Yes, you have a JMicron device. See e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120070/black-screen-when-trying-to-boot-from-ssd-on-a-raspberry-pi-4b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen when trying to boot from SSD on a Raspberry Pi 4B](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120070/black-screen-when-trying-to-boot-from-ssd-on-a-raspberry-pi-4b)

Comment: since you have a problematic cable you may want to replace it - all I'll say is DONT get a Sabrent USB to SSD cable - they won't even boot in USB2.0

Answer (score 2):

First run an upgrade `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade -y` then Update eeprom by :
`sudo rpi-eeprom-update -a` .
Then setup boot order option 4 for usb boot by
`sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit`
[0xf14] to Try USB first, followed by SD then repeat

If that does not work try setting up nvme boot (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#nvme-ssd-boot)

Comment: why would nvme boot help an SSD?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running HASSIO, an OS for HomeAssistant. The commands apt and rpi-eeprom-update are not available in there.